# Does a wrapper class for a COM interop IStream already exist?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I'm about to write a Wrapper for a COM interop IStream so that code that expects a standard .NET Stream can use it.

However it occurs to me that this sort of thing may already have been done before (although I haven't been able to find it myself with web searching).

So I'm just putting this out here in case I'm about to re-invent the wheel.

Note I've come across code implementing IStream wrapping a .NET stream but I need the reverse.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It does, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.istream.aspx).  A sample wrapper:

```
using System;
using iop = System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;

public class ComStreamWrapper : System.IO.Stream {
  private IStream mSource;
  private IntPtr mInt64;

  public ComStreamWrapper(IStream source) { 
    mSource = source;
    mInt64 = iop.Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(8);
  }

  ~ComStreamWrapper() { 
    iop.Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mInt64); 
  }

  public override bool CanRead { get { return true; } }
  public override bool CanSeek { get { return true; } }
  public override bool CanWrite { get { return true; } }

  public override void Flush() { 
    mSource.Commit(0); 
  }

  public override long Length { 
    get { 
      STATSTG stat;
      mSource.Stat(out stat, 1);
      return stat.cbSize;
    }
  }

  public override long Position {
    get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
  }

  public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) {
    if (offset != 0) throw new NotImplementedException();
    mSource.Read(buffer, count, mInt64);
    return iop.Marshal.ReadInt32(mInt64);
  }

  public override long Seek(long offset, System.IO.SeekOrigin origin) {
    mSource.Seek(offset, (int)origin, mInt64);
    return iop.Marshal.ReadInt64(mInt64);
  }

  public override void SetLength(long value) {
    mSource.SetSize(value);
  }

  public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) {
    if (offset != 0) throw new NotImplementedException();
    mSource.Write(buffer, count, IntPtr.Zero);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats a great starter for 10.

Comment: How would I go about implementing `Position`? The consumer of my stream needs it.

Comment: I figured it out, in `Read()` you need to set `Position += count` and in `Seek()` you need to set `Position = offset + (int) origin`