# Implementing Dispose on a class derived from Stream

Tags: c#, .net, stream, idisposable

I'm building a class that derives from `Stream` to wrap a COM IStream.  However I've come across an issue where I need to release the COM IStream deteministically.

Ok so that's easy just use `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` in the `Dispose` method.  However I'm not sure its that simple.  The `Stream` base class already has an protected virtual method `Dispose(boolean)`. Here is my first idea:-

```
    ~ComStreamWrapper()
    {
        if (!_Disposed)
        {
            iop.Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(_Int64Ptr);
            iop.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_IStream);
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);

        if (!_Disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                iop.Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(_Int64Ptr);
                iop.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_IStream);
            }
            _Disposed = true;
        }
    }
```

You'll notice there isn't an implementation of `Dispose()` itself.  I'm currently making the asssumption that the existing implementation on `Stream` does what I need it to.  That is calling `Diposing(true)` and `GC.SuppressFinalize`.  Is this assumption faulty?

Have I missed something?  Is there a better approach?  You see more of the basic class in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586159/does-a-wrapper-class-for-a-com-interop-istream-already-exist/2586952#2586952) to an ealier question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overriding the Disposing method and calling it from the finalizer will get the job done.  Note that you'll want to release the resources in both cases.  Thus:

```
~ComStreamWrapper()
{
    Dispose(false);
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    base.Dispose(disposing);
    if (!_Disposed)
    {
        iop.Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(_Int64Ptr);
        iop.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_IStream);
        _Disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The Stream class is abstract and doesn't have a finalizer.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm currently making the asssumption
>   that the existing implementation on
>   Stream does what I need it to. That is
>   calling Diposing(true) and
>   GC.SuppressFinalize. Is this
>   assumption faulty?

That's exactly what it does. Well, it calls Close, which is:

```
public virtual void Close()
{
    this.Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

A general tip when you want a definitive answer to what some standard class really does, open it in Reflector and look at the C# disassembly of it.

Comment: Is this general advice justifiable? What if the CLR gets patched and the code changes...?

Comment: @mafutrct - then you have to look at it with Reflector again. That tip was to find out what the class *really* does, not to find out what the *documented* behaviour is (for which information you are reliant on the documentation).

Comment: The MS documentation explicity states that you should not override Close.

"Notes to Implementers:
In derived classes, do not override the Close method, instead, put all of the Stream cleanup logic in the Dispose method. For more information, see Implementing a Dispose Method."

Comment: @bpeikes - I don't think anyone is suggested that `Close` should be overridden?

Comment: @DanielEarwicker, you're right. When I initially read your answer I thought you were saying that a Close should be implemented in the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

This dispose method:

```
  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
```

is a common pattern. I would assume that every Dispose method in the Framework looks like this (whenever the class can be derived):

```
public void Dispose()
{
  Dispose(true);
  GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

Comment: While I believe you are right, "assume" means unreliable and not trustworthy for a "correct" program.