# PInvoke and IStream

Tags: c#, pinvoke, unmanaged, istream

I have an exported function from a dll written in c++ with the following signiture:

```
Foo( LPSTREAM *pStream, UINT &Size )
```

that returns an memory stream and obviously its size.  What I am having difficulties with is creating a signiture for the exported function and then attempting to read the stream in C#.  At one point was able to use "unsafe" byte pointer to get the information, but this does not fit our requirements.

Any thoughts, examples, samples etc would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like so:

```
[DLLImport(@"mydll.dll")]
public static extern void Foo(out ComTypes.IStream Stream, ref uint Size);
```

Call it like this:

```
ComTypes.IStream Stream = null;
uint Size;
Foo(out Stream, ref Size);
```

As normal, make sure your calling conventions match (C# defaults to stdcall, C++ defaults to cdecl).

---

As an aside, why return the `Size` separate from the stream since `IStream` knows its size and will tell you if you ask it to?

See also:

- [Does a wrapper class for a COM interop IStream already exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586159/does-a-wrapper-class-for-a-com-interop-istream-already-exist)

Comment: Thanks Dave.  I made the code change and when the foo export function is executed an exception is thrown.

Comment: Message "Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{0000000C-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))." string

Comment: @Kev I've done some digging around and I'm now confident that this works. I think the problem is that you aren't returning an interface that implements `IStream`, just as the error message states.

Comment: Probably isn't a COM library and LPSTREAM is just a pointer to a struct, like the ones used with DevIL and FreeImage.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan where did you get the info that C `LPSTREAM` maps to c# `ComTypes.IStream` ?

Comment: @malat I've no idea, I answered this 12 years ago!