# Serialization/Deserialization of COM Object that Implements IPersistStream in .NET

Tags: c#, serialization, com, deserialization

I've got a 3rd party COM object that implements the IPersistStream COM Interface.

I need to write a serialize/deserialize method for these COM Objects.

```
public byte[] Serialize(MyComObject obj){ ... }
public MyComObject DeSerialize(byte[] bytes) { ... }
```

the methods i'm interested in are Load() and Save(), however, neither returns anything and my pointer skills are a bit rusty.

```
public interface IPersistStream
{
    void GetClassID(out Guid pClassID);
    void GetSizeMax(out long pcbSize);
    int IsDirty();
    void Load(IStream pStm);
    void Save(IStream pStm, bool fClearDirty);
}
```

Does anyone have any sample code for using the IStream interface within .net C# to achieve this?

Apologies if this isn't enough information.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  If the COM object already implements IPersistStream then you only need to take care of IStream if you want to use its implementation.

Comment: OK, could you elaborate on what that would look like? I'll change the OP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does a wrapper class for a COM interop IStream already exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586159/does-a-wrapper-class-for-a-com-interop-istream-already-exist)

Comment: That looks like a step in the right direction.  I guess this has devolved into a question about how to use that wrapper.