# C++/CLI wrapper for an istream

Tags: c++-cli, wrapper, iostream

I have a Native C++ library I need to wrap with C++/CLI so that an existing C# application sees a .NET interface. So far I've been doing well, but I don't know what to do with a method that takes an `istream` as an argument.

Is there an existing wrapper for `istream`? Maybe (preferably) to `System::IO::Stream`?

Comment: Have you thought of making your own wrapper?

Comment: Rolling my own would be overkill. :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does a wrapper class for a COM interop IStream already exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586159/does-a-wrapper-class-for-a-com-interop-istream-already-exist)

Answer (score 1):

I've found that wrapping istream is often unnecessary. I just create a System::StringBuilder buffer and store all input until it's ready. Then, I convert  System::StringBuilder^ -> System::String^ -> std::string -> std::stringstream and send the stringstream as the arg.