# Creating IStream object in C#

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

I'm writing a project and working with another party DLL.

Function from their DLL wants an IStream object to save result, but I can't understand how to create an IStream object.

Can anyone help me with my problem?

Comment: IStream Interface visit following link please. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.istream.aspx

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't create IStream object, because obviously it's an interface. You should rather implement this interface and pass your object. Or simply use an object that already implements it, if such object exists.

Already given answer for a similar question gives a nice example how to use IStream interface in C#.

[Does a wrapper class for a COM interop IStream already exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586159/does-a-wrapper-class-for-a-com-interop-istream-already-exist)

**Correction:**
This, however, works only if you need to use already an existing IStream inside your app, not when you need to create and pass an IStream elsewhere. For that task, see this for refence how to do that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380034(v=vs.85).aspx

And here is an example from Microsoft (used for XmlLite, not sure if it works for you)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms752876(v=vs.85).aspx

Or maybe this example, already posted by Marcus:
[http://hl7connect.blogspot.sk/2010/04/c-implementation-of-istream.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20161130125259/http://hl7connect.blogspot.sk/2010/04/c-implementation-of-istream.html)

This last link shows how to use any Stream to implement the IStream interface.

Comment: So can I create a MemoryStream object and send it to the function?

Comment: @IgorRyzhov, MemoryStream doesn't implement IStream, but Stream. That won't work. You can use any object, but it needs to implement the exact same interface as specified in the function.

Comment: @walther, i got it, thank you. But is there any C# built-in classes, that inmplements IStream or I should write my own?

Comment: @IgorRyzhov, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586159/does-a-wrapper-class-for-a-com-interop-istream-already-exist .

Comment: @walther, I've read it, but it implements Stream, not IStream, doesn't it?

Comment: @IgorRyzhov, ah, my bad. Yes, you're right. This example is useful for the situation, when you need to use IStream in your app, not when you need to pass IStream elsewhere. :(( Gonna fix the link, just a second.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a managed implementation from Microsoft now that .Net is more open source:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/IO/Packaging/managedIStream.cs

Answer (score 0):

[Implement your own stream class and inherit the IStream interface](http://hl7connect.blogspot.no/2010/04/c-implementation-of-istream.html). IStream is just a stream and can be pretty much what you decide it is as long as it is a stream (e.g. FileStream etc.)

Related: [link](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/3@5@1/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/Orcas/NetFXw7/wpf/src/Framework/MS/Internal/IO/Packaging/ManagedIStream@cs/1/ManagedIStream@cs)