# How to pass a stream from Delphi to C#?

Tags: c#, delphi

Streams are very mysterious for me, so please be patient and friendly :) I am trying to create a Stream in Delphi, which I can pass to C# as a parameter. Does anybody know how to do that?

**Note** that I am able to call the C# function from my Delphi project like down below. I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZutlhThQJ5s) to create a DLL from my C# project and to implement the DLL in Delphi.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    Stream : TStream;
    Baz : TBaz;
begin
    Baz := TBaz.Create(Self);
    // Create Stream & call Bar() with the created Stream as parameter
    Baz.Bar(?param?);
end;
```

My C# project looks like this:

```
public class Baz
{
    public void Bar(?param?)
    {
        // Get stream here
    }
}
```

I highly appreciate any help, sheers!

---

**Edit:**

- The stream should be a **file stream**

Comment: You missed out the important information: What kind of stream is it - how do you create it? If it's a file stream, you could pass the filename to C# and open the file there.

Comment: @MatthewWatson It should be a file stream, but I haven't created a stream yet since streams are very mysterious for me. My hope was to find help here :D

Comment: If you can call your c# project directly you have to be using "delphi for .Net" or delphi 8. I think this should be clarified, since not all delphi versions support .Net. Also, if you are using regular .Net streams you should be able to just pas them as you would with any other parameter.

Comment: A stream should not be that mysterious to you. It's simply an abstraction for a sequence of data that allows the same client code - the stream user - to treat physical files, socket I/O, memory buffers, and so on, in the same way.

Comment: @JonasH I've implemented my C# project as an Delphi component. Thanks for the advice, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: You may consider using an OS level abstraction that can be interfaced with both Delphi and C#. My favorite is a TCP socket which has the advantage that the same code work even if C# en Delphi programs are running on different machine. You can also use named pipes. In either case, you should open a new question with a clear subject for whatever you selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Delphi and C# have support for `IStream` interface for interoperability purposes. You can wrap any stream with `TStreamAdapter`. If you are constructing the stream on Delphi side you need to make sure that wrapped stream instance will live longer than `IStream` wrapper or you need to pass ownership of the stream to the adapter.

```
uses
  Winapi.ActiveX,
  System.Classes; 

var
  FileStream: TFileStream;
  Stream: IStream;
begin
  FileStream := TFileStream.Create(...);
  try
    Stream := TStreamAdapter.Create(FileStream);
    // use stream
    Baz.Bar(Stream);
  finally
    Stream := nil;
    FileStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

or

```
var
  FileStream: TFileStream;
  Stream: IStream;
begin
  FileStream := TFileStream.Create(...);
  Stream := TStreamAdapter.Create(FileStream, soOwned);
  // use stream
  Baz.Bar(Stream);
end;
```

Documentation:

- [System.Classes.TStreamAdapter](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStreamAdapter)
- [IStream interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-istream)
- [Does a wrapper class for a COM interop IStream already exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586159/does-a-wrapper-class-for-a-com-interop-istream-already-exist)

Of course, you can always pass filename to C# and construct the stream on C# side.

Comment: Thank you really much, that helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Streams are implementation-specific to each compiler, so you can't pass a (native) Delphi TStream to C# and expect it to work over there. Likewise a C# Stream is not compatible with a (native) Delphi TStream, so you can't go the other way as well.

It may be possible (using a lot of dirty hacks) to do some form of inter-operability between C# classes and Delphi classes, but quite frankly, it'll be a lot of work for very little benefit, in particular (no insult intended) for your current level of experience (as you consider streams "mysterious").

If it is a file you are trying to pass over, pass the file name instead and let the C# side allocate a C# stream to access it.

Edit: You can use the IStream interface to wrap the (native) Delphi TStream instance and pass this interface to C#, which then should be able to access the (native) Delphi TStream from the (managed) C# code. See Dalija Prasnikar's answer.

Comment: Indeed, they aren't compatible, but I don't call C# directly from Delphi, I've implemented the C# project in Delphi as an Unit via a DLL. A quite complicated way, but it is working very well actually.

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct. There is IStream interface that allows interoperability between C# and Delphi streams without hacks.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: Didn't know that - I've learned something new today! :-)